# Raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: python, json, yolo

So i was trying to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lg4T9iJkwhE&t=155s to achieve image detection with YOLO.

and when trying to run this code to auto download images of cell phones but it didn't work

```
import os
import urllib.request as ulib
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import json

url_a = 'https://www.google.com/search?ei=1m7NWePfFYaGmQG51q7IBg&hl=en&q={}'
url_b = '\&tbm=isch&ved=0ahUKEwjjovnD7sjWAhUGQyYKHTmrC2kQuT0I7gEoAQ&start={}'
url_c = '\&yv=2&vet=10ahUKEwjjovnD7sjWAhUGQyYKHTmrC2kQuT0I7gEoAQ.1m7NWePfFYaGmQG51q7IBg'
url_d = '\.i&ijn=1&asearch=ichunk&async=_id:rg_s,_pms:s'
url_base = ''.join((url_a, url_b, url_c, url_d))

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}


def get_links(search_name):
    search_name = search_name.replace(' ', '+')
    url = url_base.format(search_name, 0)
    request = ulib.Request(url, None, headers)
    json_string = ulib.urlopen(request).read()
    page = json.loads(json_string)
    new_soup = Soup(page[1][1], 'lxml')
    images = new_soup.find_all('img')
    links = [image['src'] for image in images]
    return links


def save_images(links, search_name):
    directory = search_name.replace(' ', '_')
    if not os.path.isdir(directory):
        os.mkdir(directory)

    for i, link in enumerate(links):
        savepath = os.path.join(directory, '{:06}.png'.format(i))
        ulib.urlretrieve(link, savepath)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    search_name = 'cell phones'
    links = get_links(search_name)
    save_images(links, search_name)
```

I got bunch of errors like this :

```
C:\Python36\python.exe "C:/dark/darkflow-master/new_model_data/part5 - get_images.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/dark/darkflow-master/new_model_data/part5 - get_images.py", line 39, in <module>
    links = get_links(search_name)
  File "C:/dark/darkflow-master/new_model_data/part5 - get_images.py", line 19, in get_links
    json_string = ulib.urlopen(request).read()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Someone please help me fix this mess,thanks.

Comment: Please include the code in the post. Its difficult for others to review on an external site

Comment: the code is just too long and it said "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details " so i don't know how to fix that

Comment: Its a good indicator to clarify the question. You've linked to a youtube video its difficult for others to quickly derive context out of that. Perhaps you could summarise what the video tutorial is about. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: No i mean i also post the code but it just can't and i don't know how to add more details

Comment: You can add more details be describing you're trying to do.

Comment: thks,please help me i have edited